# postman sending request forever, Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, postman

If the current image name exists in the db, storage returns the image corresponding to the image name and sends a return success message. Alternatively, if the image name does not exist in the db, it is implemented to return an error with a message that the image name does not exist in the db. However the case that the image exists or if it does not, these all the case, the answer  is returned, and we are trying to fix it. However, in the middle of that, there was an infinite loading of postman. I want to solve these two errors. Help me, please.

saveImg.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { dlImg } = require("../firebase");

router.post("/saveImg", async (req, res) => {
  const { imgName } = req.body;

  try {
    const imgData = await dlImg(imgName, res);
    if (imgData) {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "success", imgData });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "fail" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

firebase.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.appId,
  measurementId: process.env.measurementId,
};

// Initialize Firebase

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("“);
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: "“,
});

const db = admin.firestore();
const firebase = require("./firebase");
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

async function ulImg(imgName, imgData) {
  try {
    await db.collection("images").add({ imageName: imgName });
    const file = bucket.file(imgName);
    const contentType = imgData.includes("png") ? "image/png" : "image/jpeg";
    await file.save(imgData, { contentType: contentType });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
async function dlImg(imgName, res) {
  try {
    const imageLive = db.collection("images").doc(imgName);
    const doc = await imageLive.get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      throw new Error("image name is not exists");
    } else {
      const file = bucket.file(imgName);
      const [fileSave] = await file.download();
      const imgData = fileSave.toString("base64");
      return imgData;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (res) {
      res.status(400);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  ulImg,
  dlImg,
  db,
  bucket,
};
```

There seems to be an error in the try catch statement, so I tried various things, but it doesn't solved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.